# Total cycles in a Undirected graph

Tags: algorithm, graph

Given an undirected graph with N vertices and M edges I need to find the number of cycles in the graph. But there is a constraint.

Here is an example of it: 
Consider this graph with 6 vertices and 7 edge pairs :- A-B , B-C , C-F , A-D , D-E , E-F , B-E.

Here is the image for better understanding :
[image]

Then here 2 cycles should be counted that are A-B-E-D-A and B-C-F-E-B  but not A-B-C-F-E-D-A

So I need to find the count of the total cycles in the graph.

Comment: I my opinion, as you wrote it your question is not understandable.

Comment: @hivert i wanna add pic to make my question understand,but for that i must have atleast 10 points..:(

Comment: Just link to it, we can edit it in

Comment: @NiklasB. how to link it?

Comment: Are you looking for a [cycle basis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cycle_space#The_binary_cycle_space) of your graph? You can just find any spanning tree to do so.

Comment: Just put in an external link to the url of the image. Upload it somewhere if it's not yet online

Comment: @NiklasB. yeah..i uploaded it

Comment: **Why not** A-B-C-F-E-D-A? I want numbers like 5 and 12, but not 8.

Comment: @TimothyShields As it can be formed with help of two smaller cycles.I didnt get your statement " I want numbers like 5 and 12, but not 8."

Comment: That's still not precise enough. You need to define what it is that you want. What if the graph has a leaf sticking out? What about the complete graph with 4 nodes? These cases aren't addressed at all in what you've said so far.

Comment: @TimothyShields Leaf has no role to play in cycles.I just need to count the cycles but condition is that if suppose any cycle can be formed with help of other cycles than it is to be rejected

Comment: Yes, so what if I have the graph with nodes A, B, C, D and edges A-B, A-C, A-D, B-C, B-D, C-D? What is the answer then?

Comment: just read about the cycle space as suggested by @niklas-b and tell us why it is not what you are looking for :)

Comment: @jkbkot it is what i want but how to compute it that i am not able to understand particulary if the number of nodes are high say of range 10^4.I wanna have a pretty much efficient algorithm to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for a [cycle basis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cycle_space#The_binary_cycle_space) of your graph. You do that by finding any spanning tree of the graph (for example a DFS or BFS tree). The non-tree edges of the graph represent a cycle basis: If you connect the endpoints by the unique path through the tree, you get an element of the basis.

So if the graph is connected, the number of basis elements is `m - n + 1` (m = number of edges, n = number of nodes). If it's not connected, just decompose it into connected components and sum up the number of basis elements of the components. You get something like `m - n + c` where c is the number of connected components. Thus, if you're not interested in the actual cycles and only in their  count, you just need to find the number of connected components. You can use DFS or BFS for that as well.

Comment: How to decompose it into connected components?

Comment: what if suppose we have two connected components provided .That means according to you first we need to find connnected components than find a spanning tree for each connected componenet and the remaining edges after formation of spanning tree will count up to the answer required.Am i right?

Comment: @user for example using depth-first search. You start at any node and mark all the reachable nodes. Then you start  again on an unmarked node until there are none left. The nodes reached in each iteration are the connected components and the number of iterations is the number of connected components

Comment: @user yes, but the number of tree edges is always n - 1 so you don't actually need to find a spanning tree if you just want the number of basis cycles

Comment: it need not be tree eveytime.So i think i will always be required to find a spaning tree and then count number of unvisited edges.SEE THIS EXAMPLE AND TELL ANSWER ACCORDING TO YOU. http://postimg.org/image/m1upe09uz/6bb51107/

Comment: @user i have no time for that right now. What i meant is that the spanning tree always has n - 1 nodes for a connected graph so you don't actually need to compute it if you just want to find the cycle basis cardinality

Comment: @user accordi g to the formula every cycle basis has 15 - 12 + 2 = 5 elements